# Encopresis frustration

Tags: encopresis

I have a 6yr granddaughter that has encopresis. It's very hard to watch her mom ( a single, working mom) deal with this every day. The little one tries but it is a constant struggle. With doctor visits and different medications it still goes on. It is good to know that there is a diagnosis but with everyday life it is an on going battle. After reading many of the comments on line ,I do feel we are "Blessed" to have a little one that really tries. The problem that I see is the different schedule of each day. My daughters job (different hours) and a busy life in general are very frustrating. I am very Greatfull that "this" is the only health problem that this little one has... however I wish there was a magic pill.I would appreciate any support or suggestions.

Comment: Have you searched the site for advice on encopresis? It is a common question here. Please have a look at the questions and answers, and if they don't help you, please edit your question asking for more specific advice. You can search the site by using the search function (the magnifying glass) or by the tag "encopresis" under your question or the title. Thanks, and welcome.

Comment: What does her pediatrician say? "Encopresis" may be a diagnosis, but it's really just a symptom--of what we don't know here.

Answer (score 0):

I am a psychologist, not a doctor.

There is no any magic pills. You have to find reason of encopresis and then find a way to dismiss that reason, or make it less severe.

There are several possible reasons I can think of:

1. sphincter dysfunction. - What you should look for, how to strengthen the sphincter. Maybe some exercises.
2. Fecal type - this is normal or liquid. If it is liquid - you might get some result if you focus on what the little ones eat.

If from medical point of analyzing everything is functioning right - then psychological reasons might be:

3. Baby wearing diapers, instead of using pot (or using it rare at age arround 3 years). The way is to begin learning how to use it again - it will take a lot of time now - but this is the way.
4. It also may be a way to make mother care more for her. Then try to make some more activities with mother which should become stable(everyday, every week) and not connected to encopresis.

Tips that can help:
Care of WHAT child eats - that can help him (her) body to work better.
Care of WHEN child is eating - make her eat in certain time(for example 14.00 everyday). That might help to count a time when going to the toilet will be needed. For grown up full circle eating-toilet is around 4 hours. You can measure time for your child. Time also will depend on what was eaten - if it is something easy to digest - time will be shorter, if it is smth hard to digest - time will be a bit longer. That also can help in controlling process, after some time child will be waiting fecal coming in certain time.
Fix time that child can spend with mother, except time when encopresis occurs.